# getParent method of JComponent

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

When i print `getParent()` for a `JpopUpMenu` i get following two prints at two different scenarios.

What is the difference between,

```
javax.swing.JPanel[,558,84,167x312, layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777217,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,prefferedSize=]
```

and

```
javax.swing.JPanel[null.contentPane,0,0,167x312, layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777217,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,prefferedSize=]
```

What does **null.contentPane** means. Is it a problem if it is **null.contentPane**?

Am new to Java Swings please help.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) What are the 'different scenarios'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null.contentPane` is the name of the component / default contentPane in a `JFrame / JWindow` (ie. return value of `getName()`).
It doesn't have any defined meaning.

Comment: In this case ,null.contentPane is the parent of JPanel?

Comment: sorry, it's actually the name of the component itself. I have updated my answer